# How to implement Factory pattern using @Component and ServiceLocatorFactory without context xml in Spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-annotations

Am new to Spring. Followed online resources and implemented factory pattern without `@Componen`t annotation using `ServiceLocatoryFactory`, it is working fine.

But how to implement annotation(without context xml) based factory pattern by using `@Component` without using switch case or if/else conditions.
I followed [this](http://kh-yiu.blogspot.in/2013/04/spring-implementing-factory-pattern.html) link and implemented like below:

**Service interface**

```
public interface Printer {

    public String helloPrinter();

}
```

**Implementation 1**

```
@Component
@Qualifier("PrinterOne")
public class PrinterOne implements Printer {

    public String helloPrinter() {
        return "PrinterOne";
    }


}
```

**Implementation 2**

```
@Component
@Qualifier("PrinterTwo")
public class PrinterTwo implements Printer {

    public String helloPrinter() {
        return "PrinterTwo";
    }

}
```

**Interface for service factory**

```
public interface PrinterFactory {
    public Printer getPrinter(String printerName);
}
```

**PrinterService**

```
@Service
public class PrinterService {

    @Autowired
    private PrinterFactory printerFactory;


    public Printer processPrinter(String printerName) {
        Printer printer = printerFactory.getPrinter(printerName);
        return printer;
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.factory" })
public class PrinterConfiguration {


        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Bean
        public FactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean() {
            final ServiceLocatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setServiceLocatorInterface(PrinterFactory.class);
            return factoryBean;
        }

        @Bean(name = "PrinterOne")
        @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
        public PrinterOne printerOnePrinter() {
            return new PrinterOne();
        }

        @Bean(name = "PrinterTwo")
        @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
        public PrinterTwo printerTwoPrinter() {
            return new PrinterTwo();
        }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private PrinterService printStrategyFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/test/factory/{printer_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ObjectNode getPrinterValue(@PathVariable String printer_name)
            throws IOException {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();

        System.out.println("Test");

        try {
            objectNode.put("Test", "test");
            objectNode.put("Value", printStrategyFactory.processPrinter(printer_name).helloPrinter());

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            String errMsg = "Exception occured while executing factory";
            objectNode.put(ERROR_FIELD, String.format(errMsg, exception.toString()));
            return objectNode;
        }
        return objectNode;
    }
}
```

But i am getting below error:

```
[localhost-startStop-4] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.factory.autoscan.PrinterService com.test.factory.controllers.TestController.printStrategyFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.factory.autoscan.PrinterService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1960)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.factory.autoscan.PrinterService com.test.factory.controllers.TestController.printStrategyFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.factory.autoscan.PrinterService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.factory.autoscan.PrinterService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 28 more
```

As i am new to spring am not able to find the problem, Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the code that actually leads to the error is forgotten to be included, as well as the full stacktrace.

Comment: @M.Deinum have updated full stack trace and controller.

Comment: How are your context files (especially the configuration) loaded?